# Assign mean of values if id is not unique to respective vector index

Tags: r

For the following example, I am looking for an efficient solution. In base R only.

```
# toy data/example
idx <- c(1,2,3,3,4)
vals <- c(3,6,7,1,5)
res <- rep(NA, length = 10)

res[idx] <- vals

# gives 
res[idx]
#> [1] 3 6 1 1 5
```

What I am aiming for instead:

```
# desired output
res[idx] 
[1] 3 6 4 4 5
```

E.g. if `idx` is not unique (the case for $idx=3$), I would like to store the mean of $7+1$ instead of $1$ [last evaluated value].

Note, in the real application $idx=3$ may occur several times. Also, there can be thousands of non-unique indices/values in `idx`.

Comment: Maybe you just want `ave(vals, idx, FUN=mean)`? Or do you have gaps in your indexes that need to be filled?

Comment: Ah, I thought that does not work for averaging according to $n=1$ (denominator). Blunder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `aggregate` to get the `mean` per idx.

```
. <- aggregate(vals ~ idx, FUN=mean)
res[.$idx] <- .$vals
res[idx]
#[1] 3 6 4 4 5
```

Or using `tapply`.

```
. <- tapply(vals, idx, mean)
res[as.integer(names(.))] <- .
res[idx]
#[1] 3 6 4 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking for a base R solution due to speed, you might want to explore a `tapply`-solution like: `res <- tapply(vals, idx, mean)[idx]` over the accepted `aggregate`-solution above. (Now, the author has added a `tapply`-solution as well).

Testing suggests that it is indeed faster:

```r
idx <- c(1,2,3,3,4)
vals <- c(3,6,7,1,5)
res <- rep(NA, length = length(idx))

agg_fun <- function(res, vals, idx) { # By: GKi
  
  . <- aggregate(vals ~ idx, FUN=mean)
  res[.$idx] <- .$vals
  res[idx]
  
}

ave_fun <- function(res, vals, idx) { # By: Pax/MrFlick

  res <- ave(vals, idx, FUN = mean)
  res

}

apply_fun <- function(res, vals, idx) {
  
  res <- tapply(vals, idx, mean)[idx] |> as.vector()
  res
  
}

bench::mark(
  agg_fun(res, vals, idx),
  ave_fun(res, vals, idx),
  apply_fun(res, vals, idx)
)
  
# A tibble: 3 × 13
# expression                     min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result   
# <bch:expr>                <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>   
# agg_fun(res, vals, idx)    221.9µs  259.7µs     3710.        0B     2.43  1527     1      412ms <dbl [5]>
# ave_fun(res, vals, idx)       36µs   39.8µs    24262.        0B     2.45  9883     1      407ms <dbl [5]>
# apply_fun(res, vals, idx)   34.2µs   36.1µs    27200.        0B     5.47  9941     2      365ms <dbl [5]>
```

Also much faster on bigger samples:

```r
idx2 <- sample(1:100, 100000, replace = TRUE)
vals2 <- sample(1:1000, 100000, replace = TRUE)
res2 <- rep(NA, length = length(idx2))

bench::mark(
  agg_fun(res2, vals2, idx2),
  ave_fun(res2, vals2, idx2),
  apply_fun(res2, vals2, idx2)
)

# A tibble: 3 × 13
# expression                        min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result
# <bch:expr>                   <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>
# agg_fun(res2, vals2, idx2)    28.37ms  28.89ms      34.6    26.5MB     2.47    14     1      404ms <dbl> 
# ave_fun(res2, vals2, idx2)     4.16ms   4.57ms     220.     5.98MB     2.53    87     1      396ms <dbl> 
# apply_fun(res2, vals2, idx2)   2.74ms   2.82ms     328.     6.36MB     2.58   127     1      387ms <dbl>
```

Comment: For a comparsion, I think you should add `ave_fun <- function(res, vals, idx){ res <- ave(vals, idx, FUN = mean); res}`. Also, there is a typo in the second code chunk `length(idx)` should be `length(idx2)`. Fyi, using your toy data, `ave_fun()` is slightly slower than `apply_fun()`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion (and for spotting the bug). It's a close run here too.